# Python: Appending adding to a dictionary to with a for loop to output as json

Tags: python, simplejson

I'm bit new to python, I've trying to scrap a page using Beautiful Soup and output the results in a JSON format. SimpleJson

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json as simplejson 

webpages = (
    "page1.html",
    "page2.html",
    "page3.html"
)

my_dict = {}

for webpage in webpages:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))
    title = soup.title.string
    body = soup.find(id="bodyText")
    my_dict['title'] = title
    my_dict['body']= str(body)

print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
```

I'm only getting the results of the last page? Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An indentation can cause wonders in python , only the last line needed to be indented inside the for loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json as simplejson 

webpages = (

"page1.html",
"page2.html",
"page3.html"

)

my_dict = {}

for webpage in webpages:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))

    title = soup.title.string

    body = soup.find(id="bodyText")

    my_dict['title'] = title
    my_dict['body']= str(body)

    print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
```

or if you really want all the data in one dictioanry, then you could try:

```
my_dict['title'] = my_dict.get("title","")+","+title
my_dict['body']= my_dict.get("body","")+","+body
```

So the code may look like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json as simplejson 

webpages = (

"page1.html",
"page2.html",
"page3.html"

)

my_dict = {}

for webpage in webpages:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))

    title = soup.title.string

    body = soup.find(id="bodyText")

    my_dict['title'] = my_dict.get("title",[]).append(title)
    my_dict['body']= my_dict.get("body",[]).append(body)

print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
```

Comment: what if, for example, 'title' tag contains a coma?

Comment: The delimiter should be specified by the user , It can be modified accordingly

Comment: Because the title said "appending" , That's why I came up with this suggestion

Comment: Yes, I trying get it into on dictionary. But I've now realised that the output is the same anyway! thanks for you help.

Comment: delimiter for JSON is specified. If title and body should be lists, you he should append have his data structure initialized as `my_dict = {'title': [], 'body': []}` and do `my_dict['title'].append(title)` in each iteration

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting your dictionary each time through the loop. Tab the `print` statement over so it is included in the `for` loop:

```
for webpage in webpages:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))

    title = soup.title.string

    body = soup.find(id="bodyText")

    my_dict['title'] = title
    my_dict['body']= str(body)

    print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
```

Comment: Yup; OP, you're destroying title and body each time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying to get it in to one dictionary, but I now realize that the output is the same anyway!

Comment: If you want to put them all in one dictionary, one way is to make a dictionary of dictionaries, where the key for the subdictionary is the name of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
results = [] # you need a list to collect all dictionaries

for webpage in webpages:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))
    this_dict = {}
    this_dict['title'] = soup.title.string
    this_dict['body'] = soup.find(id="bodyText")
    results.append(this_dict)

print simplejson.dumps(results, indent=4)
```

I have a feeling, however, that what you want it is a dictionary, where keys are titles of page and values are bodies:

```
results = {}

for webpage in webpages:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))
    results[soup.title.string] = soup.find(id='bodyText')

print simplejson.dumps(results, indent=4)
```

Or using comprehensions:

```
soups = (BeautifulSoup(open(webpage)) for webpage in webpages)
results = {soup.title.string: soup.find(id='bodyText') for soup in soups}
print simplejson.dumps(results, indent=4)
```

PS. Please forgive me mistakes, if any occur, I am writing from a phone...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are destroying **title** and **body** in each iteration, there are two ways of handling it:

1. Create a list of all dictionaries as:

   ```
   all_dict=[]
   for webpage in webpages:
       soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))
       title = soup.title.string
       body = soup.find(id="bodyText")
       my_dict['title'] = title
       my_dict['body']= str(body)
       all_dict.append(my_dict)

   for my_dict in alldict:
       print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
   ```
2. Use iteration number using `enumerate()` to create different **title** and **body** names like **title1, body1, title2, body2**, etc. This way you preserve each **title** and **body** name in same dictionary as:

   ```
   for i,webpage in enumerate(webpages):
       soup = BeautifulSoup(open(webpage))
       title = soup.title.string
       body = soup.find(id="bodyText")
       my_dict['title'+str(i)] = title
       my_dict['body'+str(i)]= str(body)

   print simplejson.dumps(my_dict,indent=4)
   ```